# QGIS - how to offset raster 1 null values filled by raster 2

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, offset

I have 2 rasters ...

Raster 1 has null values of 0 which I have filled in by using values from Raster 2.

To do so, I input the following expression into QGIS raster calculator:

```
("raster1@1" = 0) * "raster2@1" + ("raster1@1" != 0) * "raster1@1"
```

This has successfully filled in the null values, but now I am wondering is there a way to offset the filled-in values?

For example, raster 1 is singlebeam data and raster 2 is multibeam data. I would like to adjust the multibeam values down to the level of the singlebeam data so it looks more realistic (without adjusting the single beam values at all)

Does anyone know if this is possible in QGIS?